# Python subprocess.run() seems to start my MS Access app in read only

Tags: python, windows, ms-access, subprocess

Python subprocess.run() seems to start my MS Access app in read only

My Python 3.7.3 script calls a MS Access app on Win 10 via subprocess.run(). When it executes the MS Access application MS Access hits an error condition and I get a pop up stating “Cannot update. Database or object is read-only”. I only hit this condition when I execute the MS Access app (for this example called: MetaQA.accdb) in python. If I double click MetaQA.accdb in explorer it runs fine. I’ve never seen this issue until I called MetaQA.accdb via subprocess.  Is subprocess running it in read-only mode? If so how do I change that?

Side note: I looked at my various MS Access apps and they seem to fail when writing into a local table, i.e. “SELECT empnum, max(transdate) AS lastpaid INTO last_staff_paid”

Variable values to the below code:

access =  C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Office/Office16/MSACCESS.EXE

commandLine = S:/ADMIN/DIS/Access Projects/AFEs/MetaQA.accdb

```
try:
    os.chdir( batchPath )   #   cd to the batch dir.

    if( args.verbose ):
        print( "changed directory to: " + os.getcwd() )
except OSError:
    print( "Unable to change directory to:", batchPath )

if( args.job ): #   run only one job
    commandLine = batchPath + args.job

    if( args.verbose ):
        print( "Running process: " + access + " " + commandLine )

    #   No timer as its assumed this is being run on the cmd line
    proc = subprocess.run( [ access, commandLine ],
        stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
        stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,
        universal_newlines=True
    )

    if( proc.returncode != 0 ):
        returnStatus = returnStatus + " The following batch job failed: " + batchFiles + "\n"
```

Comment: Try [raw strings or double backslash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2953834/windows-path-in-python) `\\\` for Windows file paths instead of forward slash.

Comment: @Parfait Thanks, my code now works as expected